# MYSQL get all the results of a date less than given value

Tags: mysql

I have a table as below

```
Eid  joinDate

1    01-01-2016
2    01-01-2016
3    28-02-2016
4    28-02-2016
5    28-02-2016
6    15-02-2016
7    15-02-2016
```

I want to get all the results of a most recent date which has data.

ex: if I give '**28-02-2016**' as input, then the results should be

```
3    28-02-2016
4    28-02-2016
5    28-02-2016
```

If I give '**18-02-2016**' as input the results should be

```
1    15-02-2016
2    15-02-2016(Most recent from 18-02-2016)
```

I tried with the below query, but it is returning only one result.

```
select Eid,max(joinDate) from Employee where joinDate<='18-02-2016'
```

But this query is not returning all the results. Also if I use group by then it will return all results less than 18-02-2016

Is there any other way to achieve this, please suggest.

Comment: group by what field? and do you have any milliseconds or seconds in timestamp?

Comment: I don't understand the first column of your result set. And this question is poor in my view. See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it using `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT t1.Eid,
   t1.joinDate
FROM Employee AS t1
LEFT JOIN Employee AS t2 ON t2.joinDate > t1.joinDate
AND t2.joinDate <= '2016-02-16'
WHERE t1.joinDate <= '2016-02-16'
  AND t2.Eid IS NULL
```

[**SQL Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a0ee29/1)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in MySQL by using a subquery in the `WHERE` clause:

```
select e.*
from employees e
where e.joindate = (select max(e2.joindate)
                    from employees e2
                    where e2.joindate <= '2016-02-28'
                   );
```